# Router load tester that is open source?

Tags: performance

For residential routers, I need a load tester that is open source; are there any recommendations?

Some testing that I would like to do is:

- Mass connections to find out max
- Simultaneously load/download/upload connections

Basically, something that is going to attempt to break my router without finding exploits, I want my router to be connection tested so I can find out its theoretical load limit.

Comment: What kind of 'loads' are you aiming to test?

Answer (score 0):

There is the Linux kernels [pktgen module](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/pktgen).